# Connection was reset in Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: networking, server, docker

I just start some docker services on Ubuntu 16.04 server. I disable ufw for testing purpose. But port is not listening to out of server. When I entered the http:// on browser , It show the connection was reset. Any Ways are available to listen this port for outside. I am a beginner in Ubuntu OS. Sorry in advace for my simple question.

```
orderer0.Myname.com:
    extends:
        file: docker-compose-base.yml
        service: orderer
    container_name: orderer0.Myname.com
    environment:
        - ORDERER_HOST=orderer0.Myname.com
        - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ORDERERTYPE=kafka
        - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_KAFKA_BROKERS=[kafka0:9092,kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092]
        - ORDERER_KAFKA_RETRY_SHORTINTERVAL=1s
        - ORDERER_KAFKA_RETRY_SHORTTOTAL=30s
        - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true

        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=MynameOrderer
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=SampleInsecureKafka
        - ORDERER_ABSOLUTEMAXBYTES=${ORDERER_ABSOLUTEMAXBYTES}
        - ORDERER_PREFERREDMAXBYTES=${ORDERER_PREFERREDMAXBYTES}
    volumes:
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/Myname.com/orderers/orderer0.Myname.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/Myname.com/orderers/orderer0.Myname.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls
        - ../config/:/var/hyperledger/config
    depends_on:
        - kafka0
        - kafka1
        - kafka2
        - kafka3
    networks:
      behave:
         aliases:
           - ${CORE_PEER_NETWORKID}
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
```

I already run the docker ps command and verified the services is started.

Comment: Please, explain how do you run container and is post exposed for container?

Comment: I just up the docker container file(yml file) with specify some ports.

Comment: Can you show your yml file?

Comment: Hey...I edited my question.

Comment: I want to listen the port 7050

Comment: on local machine, this port is show some thing like this �������� .But in server , connection was reset(on web browser).

Comment: I think you are getting reset connection cause nothing in container is listening port 7050. Possible, you need to change your `port` section.
Try to attach interactive bash and check which ports are listening: `netstat -nl | grep :`

Comment: I tried using different port number. But it is not listen to outside. Need to change any configuration for solving this issue...??You are familiar with hyperledger..?

Comment: netstat -nl | grep :7050 return:                                                                                    tcp6       0      0 :::7050                 :::*                    LISTEN